# Why does my boolean value change when it reaches the service?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm making an application in angular and I have a problem with the value of a variable.
I have an object with a boolean attribute, which is defined as a checkbox in the frontend.

```
 <div class="col-md-1">
    <input #myInputPhone type="checkbox"  class="form-control" formControlName="active" [formControl]="valForm.controls['active']">
 </div>
```

I have been debugging and to see what values come from the component, I have created this line in the submit method.

```
if(this.valForm.controls['active'].value == true)
{
  console.log('CHECKBOX MARCADO');
  this.customPoke.active=true;
  console.log('this.customPoke');
  console.log(this.customPoke.active);

}

  this.doAdd(this.customPoke);
```

This is the doAdd method:

```
doAdd(value) {

    this.resetFields('Añadiendo un usuario nuevo');


    console.log('this.customPoke doAdd');
    console.log(this.customPoke.active);
    this.pokayokesConfigService.add(this.customPoke).
      subscribe(
        data => {
          this.loadPokayokes();
          this.toasterService.popSuccess('common.messages.addSuccess');
        },
        err => {
          this.onError(err);
        });
  }
```

And now as you can see, im marking the checkbox in the front end and im checking the values in the console.

[Checkbox as HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7qwj.png)

[Console info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQkpT.png)

But the point is that once it starts the this.doAdd() method I have another log to see the full object and the value of the active atribute and its ok, but the doAdd method calls the service, when im also logging the item I to see the full object and the value of the active atribute changes.

```
add(type: PokayokesConfig): Observable<PokayokesConfig> {

  console.log('objeto que llega al add: ');
  console.log(type);

  if(type.dateLastSupervision)
  {
    type.dateLastSupervision = new Date();

  }   

  return this.apiService.post(this.baseRoute, type);
}
```

And as you can see, in [the console, it shows the item with active = false.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NerOc.png)

For your information, this is the PokayokesConfig class.

```
export class PokayokesConfig extends BaseModel<number> {

  id: number;
  active: boolean;
  codeEnabled: string;
  codeDisabled: string;
  codeSupervision: string;
  name: string;
  messageEnabled: string;
  messageDisabled: string;
  messageSupervision: string;
  localization: string;
  actualState: string;
  actualSuvervisionState: string;
  dateLastSupervision : Date;
}
```

How is this posible?

Comment: Can you attach `doAdd` method to the question?

Comment: @YongShun Added as an edit. Ty

Comment: The source code looks okay for me, but since you parse `this.customPoke` in `doAdd(this.customPoke)`, in your `doAdd` method, why not get the `value` (param) and pass to service as : `this.pokayokesConfigService.add(value)`.

Comment: I already tried that, in fact it is how it was made at the beginning, but the same thing kept happening, so I decided to try it as it is now.